# What Replaces Microsoft.Phone.Shell in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mono, monogame

I'm porting a XNA Game to iOS using VisualStudio for Mac and MonoGame... and I'm wondering what actually replaces `Microsoft.Phone.Shell`. I need to subscribe to the following events:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Launching += OnGameLaunching;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Closing += OnGameClosing;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated += OnGameDeactivated;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += OnGameActivated;
```

And I also need to save game state like this:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Add("_obj" + index.ToString(), gameObject);
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo

Comment: Yes... but how do I integrate UIKit with Microsoft.Xna.Game.Run()?